# Combining Splitline(), Enumerate and RegEx to pull data

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looking to pull names and emails from a txt file. I split lines and enumerate over them to identify the RegEx patterns. Not all names have a corrosponding email so I enumerate over names first.

Identifying names --> Because there is text between the names I want, each name is preceded by a number. Like so: [image]
Between each number/block of text, I want to search for an email. This is where I'm stuck. I get a syntax error in the marked code below. The first for-loop works, the second don't.

```
list = []


f = open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
txt = f.read().splitlines()

#k is the line counter, line is the text that is pulled out
for k, line in enumerate(txt):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
        list.append((k, line))


for i, name_tup in enumerate(list):

    l, name = name_tup
    **emails = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", txt[l:list[min(l + 1, len(list))])**
    if emails:
        new_List.append(name, emails)
print(new_List)
```

Comment: Your expression looks like it can be optimized. You might possibly give us some input strings so that we can be of any help.

Comment: Well the names always have this format:
Last name, middle name(sometimes), first name, f. DD-MM-YYYY

And the emails are just emails. I don't know if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# first: don't use list as a variable name, you overwrite a builtin function
a_list = []
# second: use context manager
with open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
# third: readlines() is simpler than read().splitlines() and does not create a temporary file-sized string
    txt = f.readlines()
for k, line in enumerate(txt):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
        a_list.append((k, line))

# fourth: enumerate is unnecessary here
for (l, name) in a_list:
     # fifth: I'd rather split your instruction into two
     # sixth: a_list contains tuples, you need the first item in a tuple
     endpos = a_list[min(l + 1, len(a_list)-1)][0]
     # seventh: now you should see what your syntax error was - single ] where ]] should be
     # eighth: txt is a list, not a string - re.findall requires a string
     emails = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", ''.join(txt[l:endpos]))
     if emails:
         # ninth: you want a tuple, make it a tuple
         new_List.append((name, emails))
print(new_List)
```

…and I am quite sure I missed some more problems.

Comment: This throws an IndexError: list index out of range at:
endpos = a_list[min(l + 1, len(a_list))][0]

I tried fiddling around with it but can't seem to create the list

Comment: Ah, of course! That's the tenth problem I missed: last element in `a_list` has index `len(a_list)-1`, not just `len(a_list)`…